# Vue deep watch not working on object property changes

Tags: javascript, vue.js, object, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a `customer` object as my initial data.  I have text fields that when someone starts typing, it adds different keys to the object.  When a new `key` is added, the watcher fires properly but if the key is edited from an existing value,  it will not.

So if I go to type in a street address, the `key` `street_address1` is added to the `customer` object so the watcher fires.  If I start editing the street address though, it won't fire anymore.

**template**

```html
<v-container>
  <v-col cols="12">
    <h2>Contact</h2>
    <div>Email Adderss</div>
    <v-text-field
      outlined
      v-model="customer.email"
      >
    </v-text-field>
  </v-col>

  <v-col cols="12">
    <v-row>
      <v-col cols="6">
        <div>First</div>
        <v-text-field
          outlined
          v-model="customer.first"
          >
        </v-text-field>
      </v-col>
      <v-col cols="6">
        <div>Lasts</div>
        <v-text-field
          outlined
          v-model="customer.last"
          >
        </v-text-field>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-col>

  <v-col cols="12">
    <div>Shipping Address Line 1</div>
    <v-text-field
      outlined
      v-model="customer.street_1"
      >
    </v-text-field>
  </v-col>

  <v-col cols="12">
    <div>Shipping Address Line 2</div>
    <v-text-field
      outlined
      v-model="customer.street_2"
      >
    </v-text-field>
  </v-col>
</v-container>
```

**script**

```js
data() {
  return {
    customer: {}
  };
},
watch: {
  customer(newData) {
    console.log("test", newData)
  },
  deep: true
},
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's a syntax issue.  The `deep` property isn't registered because it's incorrectly located outside of the watch, as though it was a 2nd watch.

Use object syntax for the `customer` watch.  The object should have two properties:

- a `handler` method (must be named *"handler"*, as in the [`watch` docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#watch))
- the `deep` property

```js
watch: {
  customer: {
    handler (newData) {
      console.log("test", newData)
    },
    deep: true
  }
}
```

<sup>It could also have an `immediate: true` property if you wanted the `watch` to run when the component is first created.</sup>